# Grave Wardens: can they block each other?

Tags: werewolv.es

Grave Wardens targetting the same avatar at night and potentially blocking each other's ability to block each other. Sounds paradoxical.

What happens in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Courtesans and Direwolves, Grave Wardens are also unaffected by roleblocks. Therefore, nothing would happen.

Comment: Thanks! This should be added in the role description then, IMO!